# Binomial coefficient with $k \geq n$

Tags: combinatorics

I am asked to figure out how many different n letter words I can write if all the letters in that word are small letters.

I guess if $n\leq 26$ then we have a number of different words equal to ${26}\choose{n}$.

But my question is: how many words can I make if $n\geq 26$?

Edit: Since I made a mistake, I believe the number of words I can make is $n!, \forall n$

Comment: what do you mean "small letters"?

Comment: @AdamHughes non capital letters

Comment: If $n > 26$, you don't have enough lowercase English letters to make a word of distinct $n$ letters.:)

Comment: By convention, $\binom nm$ is defined to be $0$ when $m>n$, and this fits with the combinatorial result: there is no word made of 27 different letters.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess if $n\leq 26$ then we have a number of different words equal to ${26}\choose{n}$.

Well, this is true if you consider $ab$ and $ba$ as the same word. If you don't, then you made a mistake.

Another way to see you made a mistake is setting $n=26$. Does the number of different $26$-letter words of an alphabet equal ${26\choose 26}$? What is ${26\choose 26}$ equal to, anyway?

---

Remember, ${26\choose n}$ is the number of possible **subsets of size $n$** of a set of size $26$. Order, in combinations, doesn't matter. In words, order usually matters.